# I want to clear input datepicker value on clicking clear button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

[image]

When the value is set using defaultValue prop it is clearing the field but, not when used value prop. package details `import { TextField} from '@material-ui/core';`

Comment: Need to see more code around what's going on here. If you use the `defaultValue` prop, you are using the control as un-controlled, letting it keep track of its value after you just seed it. If you use the `value` prop, you are using the control as controlled. It will not update or show something different unless you pass in a different `value`. So when the clear button is clicked you should then pass in null or empty string as `value`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @AlienWithPizza. the library which I am using does not have any callback that triggers on clicking Clear button. If there is a way I can listen to the click event I am plan to set the state with empty value. ```onChange``` event is not getting triggered on clicking clear

Comment: Can you be more specific about this clear button? Your question is referring to `TextField` but the image looks like some kind of date picker. Is it the clear button on the calendar in the image?

Comment: Yes it's clear button the calendar. Here is the code```<TextField
type="datetime-local"
value={formatDateAndTime(this.state.editedValue.startDateTime)
}
 onChange={(date: any) => {
const selectedDate = new Date(date.target.value);
if (selectedDate) {
this.setState((prevState) => ({
 editedValue: {
 ...prevState.editedValue,
 startDateTime: selectedDate,
},
}));
}
}}
 />```

Comment: I've tested this in the sandbox link they give you and onChange fires as expected. I suspect it may have more to do with how you are handling it. Once clear is clicked your code is going to end up with an invalid date as a `startDateTime` and maybe `formatDateAndTime` is not handling that resulting in some kind of error?

Comment: BTW it took me a while to track down the component you're using. It has been since removed in version 5. Links like this are helpful when asking the question. https://v4.mui.com/components/pickers/#native-pickers

Comment: Hi @AlienWithPizza, thanks a lot for your time. The issues is caused because of the ```required``` property in the component, I removed it and it started working fine.

Comment: Incase you are curious to know please check this code, try adding and removing ```required``` property and click on ```clear``` button. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-y4u1cc?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Nice glad you figured it out. This is why including full minimal examples are useful when posing these types of questions. Even in the comment with the code for the component the `required` property was not included. The code sandboxes they offer are great for debugging functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247686/discussion-between-vimal-swaroop-j-and-alienwithpizza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is caused because of the required property in the component, I removed it and it started working fine. check this code [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-y4u1cc?file=/demo.tsx), try adding and removing `required` property and click on `clear` button

Answer (score 0):

Provided you do not have the control marked `required`, the `onChange` should fire on clear, handing you an empty string.

We also need to handle that case properly. Testing the date for validity and rejecting invalid dates by setting it to null perhaps.

With that change, make sure `formatDateAndTime` correctly handles the case in which the date is null, and so returns an empty string.

```
<TextField
  type="datetime-local"
  value={formatDateAndTime(this.state.editedValue.startDateTime) }  
  onChange={(date: any) => {
    const selectedDate = new Date(date.target.value);
    const sanitizedDate = isNaN(selectedDate) ? null : selectedDate;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      editedValue: {  ...prevState.editedValue,  startDateTime: sanitizedDate }
    }));
  }}
 />
```